# Check for similar value with SQL

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I've two table (`t1` and `t2`) with 3 identical integer columns: `c1`, `c2` and `c3`. I want to count how many value in `t1` are in `t2`.

```
SELECT count(t1.value) FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON  (
    t1.c1 = t2.c1 OR t1.c1 = t2.c2 OR t1.c1 = t2.c3 OR
    t1.c2 = t2.c1 OR t1.c2 = t2.c2 OR t1.c2 = t2.c3 OR
    t1.c3 = t2.c1 OR t1.c3 = t2.c2 OR t1.c3 = t2.c3
)
```

It doesn't seems a good way to write it (I'll have to add some columns). Is there a better solution to write it without enumerated any possibilities?

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.

Comment: If t1 contains `c1 = 1, c2 = 1, and c3 = 2` and the t2 has the values `1` and `2` *somewhere*, should that count as 1, 2, or 3 in the final total?

Comment: I forget : `t1.c1`, `t1.c2` and `t1.c3` are all different. Idem for t2. So your example @rolfl should count **2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear... but, the way I understand it is:

Collect all the unique values in `t1`, and count how many of those unique values appear in `t2`.

Interesting problem.... instead of a straight join with all the `or` conditions, which may lead to an internal cross-product (thousands of joins and results to run comparisons on), I would state the logic as a couple of subselects ... which represent the two sets of data... the unique values in t1, and the unique values in t2.

Note, the 'union' operator does a distinct as part of the union....

```
select count(*)
from
  (
      select c1 as val from t1
    union
      select c2 as val from t1
    union
      select c3 as val from t1
  ) as t1vals,
  (
      select c1 as val from t2
    union
      select c2 as val from t2
    union
      select c3 as val from t2
  ) as t2vals
where t1vals.val = t2vals.val
```

The code looks nicer this way, but requires scanning each table three times (which I think will be better than the potentially thousands of times it may have to happen with your query......

### [I have put together an sqlfiddle for this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e87ca8/2/0)

Comment: It works fine, this is a good idea. It´s quite better than enumerate like I done, but it´s not factorized yet (maybe it´s not possible). Thanks.